# How can I duplicate or clone an element of a model in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have loaded a model from which I want to select an element, clone it and shift the clone along the X axis by a 1000 units.

By testing in the web browser console I have managed the shifting along the X axis part with the following code:

```
var tree = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().instanceTree;
var offset = new THREE.Vector3( 1000, 0 , 0 );

tree.enumNodeFragments(7836, function (frag) {
    var fragProxy = NOP_VIEWER.impl.getFragmentProxy( NOP_VIEWER.model, frag);
    var newfragProxy = fragProxy.mesh().clone();
    fragProxy.getAnimTransform();
    var position = new THREE.Vector3(
        fragProxy.position.x + offset.x,
        fragProxy.position.y + offset.y,
        fragProxy.position.z + offset.z
    );
    fragProxy.position = position;
    fragProxy.updateAnimTransform();
});

NOP_VIEWER.impl.sceneUpdated(true);`
```

But I have failed to find a way to clone initial element. Can someone help me to create a copy of an element or a copy of the geometry of an element ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of operation is currently not supported by the official [Viewer APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/).

You could potentially reverse-engineer the `FragmentList` class from the non-minified JavaScript code but you would most likely see *a lot* of unexpected behavior. The viewer does a lot of preprocessing to ensure efficient scene traversal and rendering (e.g., computing BVHs or consolidating meshes), and all these optimizations assume that the scene is static.